# Transfer „...” parameters to an other function

Tags: c, parameters, arguments

Is there a way to implement this?

```
void func2(...) {
    /*
     * Handle „...” parameters
     */
}
void func1(int n, ...) {
    func2(...);
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [stdarg.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/)

Comment: @self. No, that's not what the `stdarg` API is for.

Comment: you should do research on VA_LIST, varargs, and Variable Argument Lists...

Comment: @H2CO3 I'm pretty sure va_arg and company handle variable arguments.

Comment: @self. They do, but not in a manner OP wants them.

Comment: @H2CO3 He doesn't know he has to change the second function to accept va_list

Comment: yeah the need a starting point on the stack... so they can't be nakedly variadic.

Comment: @self. he doesn't "need to".

Comment: @H2CO3 It's as close as you can get.

Comment: @self. there are other options as well.

Comment: @H2CO3 OP is probably looking for that, maybe you should show them in an answer.

Comment: @self. Well... I already did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't. Variadic arguments cannot be forwarded. Your choices are:

- have your "inner" function take a(n initialized) `va_list` argument instead of `...` and pass that list from the caller;
- if the arguments are of the same (or convertible) types, you can make it accept an array, then parse the variadic arguments yourself and pass the array and its length to the called function.

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible according to Wikipedia. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h

> Variadic functions are functions which may take a variable number of
>   arguments and are declared with an ellipsis in place of the last
>   parameter. An example of such a function is printf. Variadic functions
>   must have at least one named parameter, so, for instance, `char
>   *wrong(...);` is not allowed in C. (In C++, such a declaration is permitted, but not very useful.) In C, a comma must precede the
>   ellipsis; in C++, it is optional.

So your `void func2(...)` is illegal.

Comment: This answer is correct, but not useful, since it doesn't address the actual question (which is about forwarding varargs), and since the OP's example is easily fixed to address the problem you describe. (I'm neither the upvoter nor the downvoter, BTW, though I do understand where both voters were coming from.)

Comment: What's written here is is true, but this wasn't the question.

Comment: Yeah, I think I interpreted the question differently. I was stating that is is illegal to write something like ```void func2(...)```

Comment: @NoWiS Yes, but nevertheless this still does not answer OP's question. This is an answer to "can I declare a variadic function without a leading named parameter?", which is **not** what OP is looking for. Yes, OP posted incorrect code, and only he is to be blamed for that only, but a non-answer is a non-answer.

Comment: @H2CO3 I see your point. I'm sorry.